# How many subliminal messages should logo include?

Tags: logo

Every logo should have a subliminal message, a subtle association, something that would explain what the business is about. But how many hidden meanings could be in a logotype? My friend, graphic designer, told me that two hidden meanings are enough as it will get too complicated and the audience won't get it.

For example, Unilever logo is very complicated.

[image: Unilever logo]

But this logo clearly states that business is about diamonds and has only one association - shape of a diamond. Therefore it's easy to understand it.

Full design project is here: https://www.behance.net/gallery/16581451/ADAMAS

[image]

Here is another example where designer shows the meaning of his logo. Here I'm particularly questioning his decision to use circle as a representation of: 1) love towards football and 2) love towards design.

Shouldn't that circle be representing only one thing?

Here is the full project for the reference: https://www.behance.net/gallery/40840727/Personal-Branding-Logo

[image: logo explanation]

Comment: You've said your friend is a graphic designer. What is it that you have extensive experience with, and understanding of?

Comment: @Confused , do you mean how do I understand the term "graphic design"?

Comment: No. I mean exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: @Confused , I have extensive experience in photography and UI/UX design. I used to do print design (business cards, brochures) and have basic understanding of logo design, but have never designed logotypes commercially.

Comment: Ok. Then this will easier to swallow. This question is utterly subjective, and completely up to the designer, and the client's desires and intentions in visual communication. There's no right or wrong. Read this: http://gawker.com/5070093/pepsis--new-logo-a-bargain-at-several-hundred-million-dollars

Comment: @Confused , for example in UI design icon should express only one thing so the user will know what he is clicking and what happens next (because uncertainty and double meaning confuse users and may lead to results unexpected for them). I thought that would be logical with logo design as well.

Comment: @Confused , Also I'm sure there some psychological studies as to perception of hidden meanings in logos and how many subliminal messages is the most effective choice. Just can't find them. Just don't think logo design is that simple and there are some guidelines to make the design work effectively :)

Comment: If you can't find these studies, and logo design is one of the primary purposes of graphic design and visual communication in commerce, there must be another means by which people are making the enormous influential and costly decisions when designing logos. Not being able to find those psychological studies you presume to be out there, easily, is a result, in and of itself.

Comment: Further, I'm not sure where you're getting this _rule_ from: " every logo should have a subliminal message, a subtle association, something that would explain what the business is about". Relax this rule, and work to the innate nature of the brand and its intentions, desires, objectives, realities and practicalities, and you'll inherently find what can and can't be said in symbolism and iconography both representative and communicative, and "cool".

Comment: The Nike Swoosh was famously created for about $35, I think. And just picked as "good enough", without any thought about its profundity, subliminal content, or otherwise. Coca-Cola's name and logo was drawn as is, in that cursive script, because the two cc's were thought to look good together, by an A**CC**OUNTANT!

Comment: I feel like the answer to this question ought to be 42.

Comment: I do not like the initial statement at all. "Every logo should have a subliminal message", Subliminal message is a widley debated issue and I think it does not really applies to Logo design in every case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often times the best logos contain a metaphor for the purpose of a company. Think yelps pie piece or FedEx's arrow. It's very challenging for a designer to come up with a visual metaphor and incorporate it into a logo. Logos have several other important requirements that must also be met: look, feel, legibility concise, small etc.

Finding and incorporating symbols that work metaphorically is an important goal in logo design, but not a necessary one. The majority of logos, brands, icons, monograms and letter types used to identify a product or company do not contain any symbolic meaning. But the best ones do.

I'm not sure any of the metaphors were meant to be subliminal. They're just incorporated subtly. A far as the super subtle meaning taken from common elements, like the person that drew three meanings from a circle outline, we get those for free by using such elements.

I read an analysis of the Firefox logo where they explained the feeling and emotion the different textures and shapes are supposed to evoke, so there is a rich world of meaning that can be communicated with shape, texture and color, but that's a little over my head.